# Deny all methods except POST with htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I am writing rest api application in php and I want to deny access to my host all methods except Post. POST method should work only,  others should throw Access denied error. How do I do that with. htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

You can use apache's [LimitExcept](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#limitexcept) Directive to allow or deny requests

> Restrict access controls to all HTTP methods except the named ones

```
<LimitExcept POST>
 order deny,allow
 deny from all
</LimitExcept>
```

Comment: No. I checked with my browser: it throws Server error. But with Postman post request it also throws Server error

Comment: Can you check apache log and post the error message here? Its works fine on my end.

Comment: At first time I wrote the answer, there was a typo in my answer which may lead to server error, can you check again with updated code?

Comment: First I tried to access the host with browser. This is the log:
api.mywebsite.com: 127.0.0.1 [03/Feb/2018:12:33:01 +0500] "GET /web/ HTTP/1.1" 500 1051 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36"
Then I tried with POST method of Postman. Here is the log:
api.mywebsite.com: 127.0.0.1 [03/Feb/2018:12:33:05 +0500] "POST /web HTTP/1.1" 500 1051 "-" "PostmanRuntime/6.3.2"

Comment: [Sat Feb 03 12:46:11.007214 2018] [access_compat:error] [pid 944:tid 796] [client 127.0.0.1:25578] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: D:/OpenServer/domains/api.mywebsite.com/web/
[Sat Feb 03 12:46:25.162023 2018] [access_compat:error] [pid 944:tid 796] [client 127.0.0.1:25580] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: D:/OpenServer/domains/api.mywebsite.com/web/, referer: http://api.mywebsite.com/web

Comment: So the code works, you have tried to access your site via GET and it denied the access.  Don't know about the `POSTMAN` request though.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this to .htaccess at the beginning

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mod-rewrite` to allow only `POST` requests.

At the top of your htaccess ,put the following rule:

```
RewriteEngine on

#if Request method isn't "POST"
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
#redirect the request to 403 error
RewriteRule .* - [R=403,L]
```